# Roll back Workflow tasks to previous step

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I implemented an approval workflow in SharePoint designer 2010 , in this workflow I assign some tasks used `Start Custom Task` action to some users, I want to know that is there any way to roll back to previous tasks in such a workflow, for example if one of users (user1) reject task by mistake and workflow create another task for next user (user2), is it possible to roll back workflow to previous step and assign task to user1 again?

I'll be appreciated if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint designer allow you to create a sequential workflow only. therefore you can't roll back to previous step. But you can using Visaul studio to create state Machine workflow, when you can passe from step to step when you want.